# Can someone explain to me how to add USDT support to my wallet? I use my own GETH node

Tags: go-ethereum

How to listen USDT contract? How to transfer my USDT to another USDT wallet? How to use both ETH and USDT in the same service? Etc. 
As you can see, I am new to these issues and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer usdt we have to call the transfer function of USDT smart contract. We can make use of the data field of ethereum transactions.

sample code::

you can make use of web3js library and ethereumjs-tx

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction; 

var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545/'))

sendtoken = async () => {

var fromAddress = "0x5Adb261Bea663ee06E568320a657E65aE91aC7167f" 
var toAddress = "0x7502CD89248e060395eA55442315abA1aD4E"
var contractAddress = '0x9950694AE66cE0D8595aA5B928CcF475dEd13d47' //contract address of usdt here
var privateKey = new Buffer('BABFD9D0D45A2E073360000000000ADEE63F387B42', 'hex') //pvt key

 
    
    

//add the abiarray of usdt contract here

    var abiArray = [{ "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "newSellPrice", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "newBuyPrice", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "setPrices", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_spender", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "approve", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint8" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "burn", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "minBalanceForAccounts", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "sellPrice", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_owner", "type": "address" }], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{ "name": "balance", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "target", "type": "address" }, { "name": "mintedAmount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "mintToken", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "burnFrom", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "buyPrice", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "buy", "outputs": [{ "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": true, "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "frozenAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "minimumBalanceInFinney", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "setMinBalance", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_spender", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_extraData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "approveAndCall", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_owner", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_spender", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowance", "outputs": [{ "name": "remaining", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "sell", "outputs": [{ "name": "revenue", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "target", "type": "address" }, { "name": "freeze", "type": "bool" }], "name": "freezeAccount", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "name": "initialSupply", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "tokenName", "type": "string" }, { "name": "tokenSymbol", "type": "string" }, { "name": "centralMinter", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "_spender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Approval", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Burn", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": false, "name": "target", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "frozen", "type": "bool" }], "name": "FrozenFunds", "type": "event" }]



    var contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, { from: fromAddress })

    var gasprice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    const gaslimit = 57684 
    const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress);
    const txFee = (gasprice * gaslimit)
    console.log(`transaction fee will be ${txFee / 1000000 } eth`)
    var amount = web3.utils.toHex(1000000000000000000)

    var rawTransaction = { "from": fromAddress, "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasprice), "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(58000), "to": contractAddress, "value": "0x0", "data": contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(), "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count) }

    var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    const result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex')).catch(function (e) {

            console.log(e.message);
    })
    if(result)
    {
        console.log(`transactionhash ${result.logs[0].transactionHash}`)
    }
    
 

}
sendtoken().catch(function (e) {
console.log(e.message)
})
```

usdt token contract : https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7

or you can simply make use of metamask browser extension and import the token. metamask is capable of handling both ether and erc-20 tokens

Comment: Hi @akshay-dev, I am working usdt integration. I used this [smart contract code](https://www.programmersought.com/article/63475786572/) for usdt to generate abi and bin file using solidity compiler. and it created multiple bin and abi files. my question is how do i identify which abi to use?

Comment: @satya-p91 usdt contract abi is available at https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was looking at this [link](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7). this does not have contract code or abi.